# Facebook login connect

Tags: facebook

I want **facebook login** in my website

For that I followed these steps:

1)Created a demo site at developers (i uploaded the image as well)

2)Copied the app id at the place where required

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '<MY APP ID>',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
  <div class="fb-login-button">Login</div>
```

3)I got the **fb login button** as shown in image:

[image]
on clicking the button a new window is popped up asking fb username and password and after coming back it shows this error

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=158742990907100&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D5%23cb%3Dfbf1cdd54%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ffa53db99%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df27abde948&sdk=joey&display=popup&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&domain=localhost&fbconnect=1&from_login=1&client_id=158742990907100 from frame with URL http://localhost:8080/Befundo/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

The properties I set for my app is :
I am not sure about **APP NAMESPACE**,**APP DOMAIN**,**SITE URL**
[image]

I am getting one more problem, when I click Login button twice it logs this message in the console of Browser::

```
FB.login() called when user is already connected.
```

and do nothing.

Please shed some light where I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please empty your "App Domain" field on fb application and update website url as your domain name not full path.like "http://localhost"

Comment: I removed App Domain but event then showing the same error......

Comment: my local server is running on that port......

Comment: Using a port is just fine and does not cause problems.

Comment: Could you please test your initial code with firefox instead of chrome?

Comment: You might want to consider using the channel file ([read here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)) which sometimes help with this type of errors, also, if you use this: *FB.login(function(response) { console.log(response); }, {scope: "PERMISSIONS_LIST"})* what does it print to the console? The error you're getting does not necessarily mean that it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login button is working as expected, and it's connecting user (which is confirmed by message that came after second click on the login button).

Next message is not an error in your code (it's because of cross-domain policy applied to JS-SDK trying to communicate with Facebook):

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL ... from frame with URL ... Domains, protocols and ports must match.

You can (probably) suppress it by passing self-hosted `channelUrl` to `FB.init`. (see [`FB.init` documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/))

You also seems to do nothing after the user is connected. Read [documentation for `FB.login`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) to figure out what you should do after user is logged in...